# Rewrite PHP variables from URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example I want to change:

> www.example.com/forum/thread?id=1&topic=hello

to

> www.example.com/forum/thread/1/hello

I've looked around and modified my .htacess file to look like this to modify these URLs

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) thread.php?id=$1&topic=$2 [NC,L]
```

I keep getting a 404 error saying that the file doesn't exist. I'm wondering if it's because I'm removing the .php from the file first using this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But then when I remove that rule and go to thread.php?id=1&topic=hello it just breaks everything and gives me masses of errors

Comment: In which folder have you stored that file? Do you use `RewriteBase`?

Comment: by using this rule `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` you are basically turning `www.example.com/forum/thread/1/hello` into `www.example.com/forum/thread/1/hello.php`, you need a better regexp to remove the ".php" from URL and have your arguments passed like you want

Comment: I don't understand. URL rewriting goes usually the other way around.

Comment: I found that from this website and so far whenever I've added .php to the end of a url it removes it @Kaddath

Comment: the file is in a folder called forum and that is inside the root and I don't use RewriteBase @NicoHaase

Comment: @TheWelshManc i tested your rewrite rules on local environment. for me they work. Are there more rewrite rules inside your .htaccess? Maybe a different rule get applyed? Did you check with rewrite log?

Comment: "masses of errors" And what would those errors be?  It could indicate that you are at least actually getting to the desired file.

Comment: It goes to _a_ file, but not _the_ file, it now thinks the very end of the url is a `.php` file and not the thread bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you state that you want to change:

www.example.com/forum/thread?id=1&topic=hello to www.example.com/forum/thread/1/hello

However, that is backwards.

The address that you rewrite **to** needs to be the address that the server can interpret. So, www.example.com/forum/thread/1/hello should be the "friendly" address that the user enters and the rewrite should **add** the .php extension (although with a rewrite, this will not be visible to the user in the address bar)

Try this:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?thread/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) /thread.php?id=$1&topic=$2`

The reason that you are probably getting errors going to thread.php is that you have a rule to remove the .php (which now the server will not be able to render the page). With the above rewrite rule, you will get to it by going to :
www.something.com/thread/1/hello

Comment: The previous `RewriteRule` works but now it thinks that thread is a directory and not a `.php` file, it thinks that the hello is a `.php` file

Comment: In the example above, you have $1.php. That will add a .php to whatever the first variable in your rewrite rule is. You want to make sure in the rewrite rule that you  specify the php page you should go to (ex. thread.php) then assign the variables to the php variables. (ex. id=$1&topic=$2).

Comment: Yeah my code does say that, it's pretty much the exact same but you've added a slash and question mark

Comment: Did you remove the other rule that adds the .php?

Comment: Yes I did, I'm using this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?thread/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) /thread.php?id=$1&topic=$2` only now

Comment: Just to try it, can you remove the rewrite conditions? Make sure the rewrite engine is on: RewriteEngine on Then, just put in your rule: RewriteRule ^/?thread/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) /thread.php?id=$1&topic=$2
Then, to make sure it isn't cached in the browser, try opening an incognito browser window and go to your page?

Comment: The page still loads but I'm still getting errors where css isn't loading or any scripts as it tries to look for them inside the thread directory even though thread is a file not a directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185217/discussion-between-vlnflt-and-thewelshmanc).

Answer (score 0):

Your rule will never get applied because you are using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` this condition checks your filesystem to see if `/forum/thread/1/hello.php` exists and if it doesn't  then your rule is ignored.   Simply comment out or remove that condition from your rule .

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^thread/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) thread.php?id=$1&topic=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Didn't work either, every single suggestion isn't working